# Same font-size on H2 tag looking different size on website

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts, font-size

I have `h2` with font size `1.3em` and on different places it appears with different sizes.

One of `h2` is in:

```
<div class="col col-lg-4"></div>
```

and another one is in:

```
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-12"></div>
```

But both are on the same page. why should it look different?

Body font size is `24px;`

Comment: `em` gets its size from the nearest parent with a set font. Use `rem` and it will be based on the body's font size

Comment: Thank you. It worked..!!

Comment: Could you let me know what is missing in my answer?, so I can adjust and you accept.

Answer (score 1):

`em` represents the calculated font-size of the element.

If used on the font-size property itself, it represents the *inherited* font-size of the element, and therefore it can vary based on which font is set on its parent(s).

Use `rem` instead, as it will be based on the root element

Answer (score 0):

1. To make style rules that depend only on the **default font size**, another unit was 
   developed: the `rem`.
2. The `rem`, or root `em` is the font size of the root element of the document. Unlike 
   the `em`, which may be different for each element, the `rem` is constant throughout 
   the document.
3. This means that `1rem` equals the font size of the html element (which for most 
   browsers has a default value of `16px`).